# Scala: "reassignment to val" x, but x is var

Tags: scala, var

I have the following piece of code

```
class A(var x: Int, var y: Int){

}

class B(x: Int, y: Int) extends A(x,y){

    def setX(xx: Int): this.type = {
        this.x = xx
        this
    }
}
```

but it gives the following error:

> `error: reassignment to val
>       this.x = xx
>              ^`

I don't know whats happening since x and y should be variables. WHat's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I haven't seen this done before, but it just must be that x in class b is a val. Try setting it to var in B and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a collision of the names of member variables with the names of the constructor arguments.

The obvious workaround compiles just fine:

```
class A(var x: Int, var y: Int)

class B(cx: Int, cy: Int) extends A(cx, cy) {

    def setX(xx: Int): this.type = {
        this.x = xx
        this
    }
}
```

The issue doesn't seem to be new, here is a llink [to a forum entry from 2009](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/968.html). It has a posting with [literally the same error message in the same situation](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/968.html#comment-2501).

The root cause is that constructor arguments can be automatically converted into private `val`s, because they can be referenced from the methods of the object:

```
class B(cx: Int, cy: Int) {
  def foo: Int = cx
}
```